# Python:Function takes no arguments

Tags: python, function, tkinter, arguments, subprocess

When I run this code I get the error message:

```
File "Start.py", line 22, in <module>
  c.lo()
TypeError: lo() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I don't know exactly why I am getting this error could someone please explain?
I know it's saying that I put an argument when calling that function but I don't understand why that is?

If someone could shed some light on this issue that would be great.

```
import subprocess as sp
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)

class Console:
    def Start():
        proc = sp.Popen(["java", "-Xmx1536M", "-Xms1536M", "-jar", ".jar"],stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,)
    def lo():
        while True:
            line = proc.stdout.readline()
            text.insert(INSERT,line)
            text.pack()
            if (line == "Read Time Out"):
                proc.stdin.write('stop')
            if (line == "Unloading Dimension"):
                text.insert(INSERT,"Ready for command")
                text.pack()

c = Console()
c.Start()
c.lo()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, that is because `lo()` is a method of the class `Console` which is always passed the instance as first argument. So `lo()` must define a parameter (mostly called `self`) to hold that argument:

```
class Console:
    def start(self): # functions and methods should have lowercase names
        self.proc = sp.Popen(...)
    def lo(self):
        line = self.proc.stdout.readline()
        ...
```

I am surprised that your `Start()` call worked; it has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Methods always get the instance as the first argument.
Your method definitions should look like:

```
def some_method(self):
    # do_stuff
```